# Managed cryptographic algorithms are running even after enabling FIPS in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, cryptography, sha, fips

I have enabled FIPS on my local Win 10 machine by editing security policies . I observed that when I try to initialize any managed cryptographic algorithm (like  RijndaelManaged , AesManaged , SHA1Managed )  , application throws below error

[image]

But for an existing web application , on the same machine , I am able to initialize all these classes .

1. What could be the reason for FIPS not reflecting in an application but working as expected (blocked non compliant cryptographic methods) on all other applications ?
2. Has anyone come across such a scenario and is it somehow possible to override the FIPS settings in application ?
3. If yes , then how to ensure FIPS compliance for all applications running on a web server ?

Here is the test code I used

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var v1 = new RijndaelManaged();
     var v2 = new AesManaged();
     SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed();
 }
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need FIPS compliance?  FIPS disables many good algorithms and usually weakens security, so you should avoid it unless absolutely required.  Also, SHA-1 isn't secure, and even if it's allowed now, you should probably switch to SHA-256 just for security's sake.

Comment: @bk2204 Thanks for your comment. FIPS is unfortunately needed and the snippet above is just for testing if they are getting blocked.